# lightning nodes cannot find route

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

I have two lightning nodes, Bob and Charlie (using bitcoind backend with LND).

They both have an open and funded channel with this testnet faucet:

https://faucet.lightning.community/

Both nodes have a `50000 sat` local balance, and a `49056 sat` remote balance.

Bob created an invoice for `100 sats`, but Charlie cannot find a route to Bob to pay that invoice.

Here's the `payment_request` for the invoice (note this on testnet):

```
lntb1u1psnjevnpp5dt60ltx4pwxw24ze4e6vx6fatfpsah7a629fqxnp2ufjawpe0apsdq5w3jhxapqwpshjmt9de6qcqzpgxqyz5vqsp56mzmrleumdkj92q64l99gjatyrcm7l7nlur3uqq82de2v8fmsfvs9qyyssqult5ngct3d447vcyjt0pyh3y0qfmaghmlhf488vera3zd0se9pnx77g9jxufpesc9j3ha5nflhnkx04c4kqgsgjhjjp2jqfdsk79jcqpl38ee3
```

Why can't Charlie pay Bob?  I figured they would use the channel to the testnet faucet as a middle hop.

Bob has already connected to Charlie.  Charlie appears in Bob's list of peers, and likewise Bob appears in Charlie's list of peers.

Comment: How many blocks have been found since the channels were established? I am asking because the funding TX usually needs to be buried deep enough until gossip announces the channel